# Python: Simulate Keypresses

Tags: python, window, keypress, simulate

I want to build something like a programming tastature for my soon-arriving windows tablet.
I don't want to use the normal windows 8.1 tastature, because it would take a long time to get 
brackets or things like that, so I wan't to build one myself, with buttons, where I need them.

But I've got one problem. I searched around using Google, and I saw, I'm not the only one with that problem - but I didn't find a simple solution either - so:
How do I simulate keypresses to a window?

I'm looking for something like

```
Sendkey("S")
```

Another problem was, that the focused windows would be my own tastature at this point, but I want to send the text to another window I clicked before...

If you know the solution, please answer amateur-friendly.

+Thank you for hopefully coming answers.

Comment: Try [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) or [sendkeys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys/0.3)

Comment: I'll try SendKeys(), but I guess my second problem Would be still there..